java/maven unable to read file from resources folder
I am running some junit tests, and in the main/java part of my project I have a class that needs to read an xslt stylesheet from the resources folder, which is in a subfolder resources/xslt/mystylesheet.xsl. I have done lots of googling around and found lots of stuff like this.
I have this validation method in my class (not unit test)
private void validateInput(NeptuneXmlPipelineElement input) throws Exception {
    
    
    ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    File f = new File(classLoader.getResource(stylesheetPath).getFile());
    

    // other things I have tried....
    // InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(stylesheetPath);
    // InputStream is = MyAppClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(stylesheetPath);

    // I tried this to test some other files in the resources dir, but all were not found
    // InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("log4j2.xml");


    if (!f.exists()) {
        String errorMsg = "unable to locate xslt stylesheet " + stylesheetPath;
        input.getConversionResult().addMessage(errorMsg);
        throw new FileNotFoundException(errorMsg);
    } 

}

when I look in my project target/classes folder I see this:
└───xslt
    │   mystylesheet.xsl

The thing is...this all used to work. I have made a lot of changes to the project, and when I went to start re-running a bunch of this tests, this was failing.
Is it because it can't find the files when I am running from a test environment?
Here is a snippet of my test:
@Test
public void testPipelineWorkflow() {
    String filePath = "src/test/resources/xml/mockup1_with_doctype.xml";
    String stylesheetPath = "xslt/mystylesheet.xsl";

Since the src/test folders are not exported to the target dir, when using files in the src/test/resources dir I just use the relative path as shown above...but since the stylesheet is exported to the target dir, loading as a resource should work.
Another idea...
I created a tester class with a main method. I wanted to see if the error was caused by the fact that the code execution was originating in a test case (it wasn't...)
anyway, my tester had this method:
public void testResource() {
    String xsltPath = "xslt/mystylesheet.xsl";
    
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xsltPath);
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(xsltPath);
    System.out.println("is input stream null? " + is);
    System.out.println("is url null? " + url);
}

the code above had the same error not finding the stylesheet...but when I changed xslt/mystylesheet.xsl' to just xslt' I did not get a null value...suggesting it can see the folder but not the files inside.
I tried adding a `/resources/resource/include/directory' in the pom as per the maven docs, but when I did that the files/folders in resources were not exported in the build.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?
thanks!!

The getResource(..) part is correct but then ..getFile() is wrong.. use .getResourceAsStream(..) instead and handle via InputStream...

Hi, I've already tried that...in the commented code I tried both getResource() and getResourceAsStream() and in the if block did if is == null....had same result

Then there is something else wrong...

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the following to my pom:
<resources>
    <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources/xslt</directory>

    </resource>
</resources>

I have a remaining issue which is that the dir structure is not preserved in target/classes...all the files are copied to the main dir. That is not critical right now, so living with it for now.
